# How do I vertically center my images on a page

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

If you scroll down to the sub-section entitled "Our qualifications to recycle electronics" on this [page](http://click2recycle.ca/click2recycle-test-page-main-section-removed/), you will see 3 graphics that represent the different qualifications. I would like to ensure that they are both horizontally centered within their column and vertically centered with each. I have the first part down but I am struggling with the second. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, use jsfiddle or place the code in your question. Otherwise, your question is not useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting a JS or CSS solution?

CSS: on #x-content-band-19

```
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
```

Javascript: Just take the container height of those 3 divs, get the height of each child, subtract the diff and divide by 2. So like.

```
var ph = $('#x-content-band-19').height();
var ih = $('img').height();

$('img').css({top : (ph - ih) / 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, a simple `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`
on `div#x-content-band-19` (the images' parent) should suffice.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/) is a nice link in CSS tricks. Hope this helps...

The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to each other on a line are lined up.

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```